# call a javascript from php and store the return in a variable

Tags: javascript, php

I am wondering if there is any way to call a javascrip function from php and store the return value of the function in php variable.

Something like:

```
<?php
  var p = test("something");
  echo p;
?>
<script>
 function test(elm){
     return elm+" anotherthing";
 }
</script>
```

Comment: One at server side one at client side,

Comment: @LozCherone SO seems to have answer every thing..

Comment: not everything, but answer to these type of questions have already been answered/closed many times, i try to get in there before less par users pop in the answers ;p...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call and evaluate a javascript function from php code.
You could however make a request (e.g. AJAX) from the javascript test() function to your php code and read the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Javascript is executed on the client and PHP on the server. By the time your PHP code runs the Javascript function doesn't even exist yet.